# Redis, find by hash, find by field value

Tags: hash, redis

I want to create hashes with books info in redis, for instance:

`HMSET books key "83-7197-669-0" title "Access. DB desing"  price 79.0 publisher "Helion" year 2002
 HMSET books key "83-7197-786-7" title "Access XP"  price 65.0 publisher "Helion" year 2003`

Then I just want to find a book with a key `83-7197-669-0`, I tried:

1) `HGET books key "83-7197-669-0"
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hget' command`

2) `HGETALL books
 1) "key"
 2) "83-7197-786-7"
 3) "title"
 4) "Access XP"
 5) "price"
 6) "65.0"
 7) "publisher"
 8) "Helion"
 9) "year"
10) "2003"`

I dont know why, but I see here only the second book ..

Next, I wanted to find a book with a given price, with no success. I dont even know what to try. Any ideas?

Comment: @tabreaz answer is the valid solution for your requirements, but if you'll need to "find by field value" in the future you should check the RediSearch module

Comment: The reason `HGETALL` returns only the second book is because your second `HMSET` overwrote the fields in the `books` key. If you want to keep them separate, treat `books:` as a namespace and add indexes (which you can manage with `INC` or `HINCRBY`). So it should be `HMSET books:1 ...` and `HMSET books:2 ...`. Then you can use `HGETALL books:1` and `HGETALL books:2`. Your application logic would have to handle looping the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSET in redis is like a MAP of MAP, where the books in your example is the key of outer map, where as the `key, title, price`, and other fields are like keys of inner map.

To get book by key, you can set `key` as HSET name which and use HGET `key` to get the book by key.

```
HMSET books:83-7197-669-0 title "Access. DB desing"  price 79.0 publisher "Helion" year 2002

HGETALL books:83-7197-669-0
```

should return all the fields of the HSET. I hope this gives you good start to redis Hashes.

Comment: But it is possible to find a book with a given price then?

Comment: OK, I found a way: `HGET key:"83-7197-786-7" price `

Comment: No from the above structure, if you want to get books by price range you have to consider storing them in sorted set (ZSET, which is sorted by scores which can be price in this case). Similar to Indexes in RDBMS, you have to index them in other sets and query back the actual rows by keys.

`ZSET books <price_of_book> 83-7197-669-0`
then you use `ZRANGEBYSCORE books 70.0 80.0` this will return all the books within that price range.

Then you can take the id's and hit HGETALL books:<id> good read on this [https://redis.io/topics/indexes]

Comment: `127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET books:83-7197-669-0 title "Access. DB desing"  price 79.0 publisher "Helion" year 2002
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd books 79.0 books:83-7197-669-0
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebyscore books 79.0 79.0
1) "books:83-7197-669-0"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL "books:83-7197-669-0"
1) "title"
2) "Access. DB desing"
3) "price"
4) "79.0"
5) "publisher"
6) "Helion"
7) "year"
8) "2002"`

Answer (score 2):

As you probably see, you are having all those attributes like `"key"` and `"title"` in your Redis hash.

Solution is simple, just omit the key and store rest of the data in serialized form. Redis is basically key-value store on steroids, so turn the first command to

`HMSET "83-7197-669-0" title <title> price <price> ...`

Depending on your use case, you could also use `hset`, store everything in `books` and encode values as a single serialized entry.

If you are looking way to access Redis through multiple keys, you are likely using a wrong tool. Relational data stores are better for that; Redis is still high-speed key-value store with some nice extra stuff baked in.